# Pagination issue in React.js

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I've created Pagination component but have got issues while implementing it into my Characters component.
I'm getting prev and next buttons, but instead of page numbers I'm gettin NaN.
Please advise where is my mistake?
Is there an issue with Pagination props?

Pagination.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Pagination = ({
  data,
  RenderComponent,
  title,
  pageLimit,
  dataLimit,
}) => {
  const [pages] = useState(Math.round(data.length / dataLimit));
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  function goToNextPage() {
    setCurrentPage((page) => page + 1);
  }
  function goToPreviousPage() {
    setCurrentPage((page) => page - 1);
  }
  const changePage = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    const pageNumber = Number(event.target.textContent);
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  const getPaginatedData = () => {
    const startIndex = currentPage * dataLimit - dataLimit;
    const endIndex = startIndex + dataLimit;
    return data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  };

  const getPaginationGroup = () => {
    let start = Math.floor((currentPage - 1) / pageLimit) * pageLimit;
    return new Array(pageLimit).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>

      <div>
        {getPaginatedData().map((d, idx) => (
          <RenderComponent key={idx} data={d} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="pagination">
        <button
          onClick={goToPreviousPage}
          className={`prev ${currentPage === 1 ? "disabled" : ""}`}
        >
          prev
        </button>

        {/* show page numbers */}
        {getPaginationGroup().map((item, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            onClick={changePage}
            className={`paginationItem ${
              currentPage === item ? "active" : null
            }`}
          >
            <span>{item}</span>
          </button>
        ))}

        {/* next button */}
        <button
          onClick={goToNextPage}
          className={`next ${currentPage === pages ? "disabled" : ""}`}
        >
          next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The file where I want to implement the Pagination component.

Characters.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { CHARACTERS_PAGE_URL } from "../../api/rickNMortyApi";
import { Loading } from "../../components/Loading/Loading";
import { Character } from "./Character";
import { Pagination } from "../Pagination/Pagination";
export const Characters = () => {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetch(CHARACTERS_PAGE_URL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(({ results }) => {
          if (results && Array.isArray(results)) {
            setCharacters(results);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!characters) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-4 font-mono text-green-500 ">
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <div className="m-4 ">
          <label>Species</label>
          <select name="species" id="species">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="human">human</option>
            <option value="alien">alien</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Status</label>
          <select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="alive">alive</option>
            <option value="dead">dead</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="m-4">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <select name="gender" id="gender">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="genderless">genderless</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Characters</h1>
      <Pagination data={characters} />
      <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-5 grid-rows-4 gap-4">
        {characters.map((character) => (
          <div key={character.id}>
            <Character character={character} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Getting the below error in console]

Comment: Could you provide an image of your error?

Comment: printscreen added

Answer (score 0):

I've added
 and now I can see prev, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, next
but charcters do not change if I click on the page number

When I try to add dataLimit={20} as a props for Pagination I'm getting an arrow below:
**Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**